# Dojo dijit.form.FilteringSelect not setting value in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, select, dojo

I have an issue with IE8 when executing the below code on a Dojo dijit.form.FilteringSelect widget.  I don't get an error message when executing the below code, it just doesn't set the value.  It works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but ofcourse not IE8.  Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

dijit.byId("tracking_system_select_id").set("value", 7);

Answer (score 0):

I know that Dojo Selects don't work well with numeric values:

> For best results, only use dijit/form/Select with a store whose items' identities are strings.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/selects_using_stores/

I don't know if FilteringSelect has the same limitation, but that might be something to try.

Comment: Jeremiah, thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using a string value as the identity and that didn't work either.

Comment: By "didn't work", do you mean there's no visibile change? Does get("value") return anything different? Also, have you called startup() on the widget (only matters if you created it programmatically)?

Comment: No visible changes, also I added startup() on the widget.  Below is a post from me where I have some code showing what I added for testing and the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I am calling the following to set the value, I changed it from 7 to "7":

```
dijit.byId("tracking_system_select_id").set("value", "7");
```

and then I call the following to test what value is:

```
console.log("Main.trackingSystemId: " + dijit.byId("tracking_system_select_id").get("value"));
                        console.log("Main.trackingSystem: " + dijit.byId('tracking_system_select_id').attr('displayedValue'));

var test = dijit.byId('tracking_system_select_id').get('value');
if (typeof test === 'string'){
    console.log('typeof string');
} else if (typeof(test === 'number')){
    console.log('typeof number');
} else {
    console.log('typeof unknown');
}
```

and the log entries received are:

LOG: Main.trackingSystemId:
LOG: Main.trackingSystem:
LOG: typeof string

I have also added .startup() to the creation of the FilteringSelect.  Changing from a numeric identifier to a string identifier made no difference.  The identifier values in the data store are also strings so I don't have a string to numeric problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is what I found.  I tried creating a dijit.form.FilteringSelect box and setting its default value at the time of creation and it works in Firefox and Chrome, but once again not in IE8 or IE9.  I'm going to give up and accept that it doesn't work in IE.

Would be nice if Dojo fixed this.